# Mysql IN condition for and operations

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have expertise table that have user id and expertise id. Each user might have multiple expertise. Now I want to get all users that must have all expertise in range, like (1,2,3,4,5,......so on).

IN condition is only used for OR operation so how can I get expected result lets say by using IN condition with AND operation. Or is there any other operator or trick that can be used.

EDIT:

Let me add bit more explanation. Customer select expertise like physics, math, chemistry ...... and so on. So I have expertise and I need to get all user ids from expertise table that satisfy all selected expertise. So I need user who is well versed in math, physics, chemistry and so on.

All data is in one expertise table.

Current query is like this

Select user_id from expertise where expertise_id IN (1,2,3,4)

but this is true for all user who have one of these expertise but I need all users who have all these expertise.

Comment: You can use All operator

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you are asking something which is logically impossible. An attribute for a record can't be both `1` and `2`, for example. I think you are looking for an `exists`.

Comment: Well let me explain, user must have all expertise like physics, math, chemistry and so on. So those records where user only have physics but not math are not needed.

Comment: How do we know how many expertise are there?

Comment: Well I have an interface where user tick expertise so I have an array. I know exact number of expertise. For example (1,2,3,54,5)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want all the user_id returning which have all the expertise (and possibly more) that are in the IN clause.

If so select the users_id, GROUP BY the user id and COUNT the DISTINCT expertise id that match. Return the users_id for those where the count is the same as the number of ids you are searching for.

```
SELECT user_id 
FROM expertise 
WHERE expertise_id IN (1,2,3,4)
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT expertise_id) = 4
```

Comment: Thanks. I am still trying to find a situation where it might fail or edge cases but its working.

Answer (score 0):

You could verify the number of expertises that match your list, and require that this number equals the size of your list. Here is an example, for when your list of required expertises has 5 elements:

```
SELECT *
FROM   users
WHERE  5 = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT expertise_id)
            FROM   user_expertises
            WHERE  user_id = users.user_id
            AND    expertise_id IN (1, 2, 3, 13, 18))
```

The `DISTINCT expertise_id` can be replaced by a simple `*` if it is certain that the user_expertise table has no duplicate *(user_id, expertise_id)* pairs.

Of course, you'll have to use the proper table names and columns names. This is just a template.

Comment: I might be something along the lines select user_id from expertise where expertise_id IN(1,2,3,5)